# PostgreSQL: print names of people who are students and the count of students from postgrad are more than undergrad for that course

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a PostgreSQL and have gone horribly wrong.

I need to print names of people who are students and the count of students from postgrad are more than undergrad for that course

`select p.name from Person p join Course c on (p.course=c.id) join Student s on (c.st_info=s.id) group by p.code,p.name having count(s.type='undergrad') > count(s.type='postgrad');`

Comment: This sounds like two queries, one listing students and one for counting

Comment: No, I just have to print the names of the people who have taken the course and in that course there are more postgrads than undergrads

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: I see. I think you need to show us the table structure for the 3 tables. I have a hard time understanding the relationship between person and student

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. Gordon was able to figure it out. Please refer to the answer for reference. I made 1 change in it though. I liked another table. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would identify the courses using logic such as this:

```
select c.id
from Course c join
     Student s
     on c.st_info = s.id
group by c.id
having sum( (s.type = 'postgrad')::int ) > sum( (s.type = 'undergrad')::int );
```

I'll let you figure out how to get the students who are actually in the courses.

Notes:

- Your logic in the `having` was reversed.  That is a pretty basic error.
- `count()` counts the number of non-NULL values.  The boolean expressions are probably always non-NULL, so they will return the same values.  `sum()` is what you want.
- Your data model doesn't really make sense.  Why does `course` have a student id?  Why does `person` have a course id?

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful. Its a dummy data for practice purposes. I'm learning how to fetch data right now.